# Cant install Vowpal Wabbit on Mac

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am trying to install Vowpal Wabbit  via pipenv install. But failed with the following error.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/johnchan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ATEC-s3CStNz5/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/6b/nnn57rdn6ps7h0pn78h8hnrm0000gp/T/pip-install-rjmca3xe/vowpalwabbit/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/6b/nnn57rdn6ps7h0pn78h8hnrm0000gp/T/pip-install-rjmca3xe/vowpalwabbit/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/6b/nnn57rdn6ps7h0pn78h8hnrm0000gp/T/pip-record-80qogib2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/johnchan/.local/share/virtualenvs/ATEC-s3CStNz5/include/site/python3.8/vowpalwabbit Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

We just released version 8.9, which comes with binary wheels. If you try installing now it should be simpler:

```
pip install vowpalwabbit==8.9.0
```

If there are still issue can you provide the full log output?